# In Python, what's the correct way to instantiate a class from a variable?

Tags: python, instantiation

Suppose that I have class `C`.

I can write `o = C()` to create an instance of `C` and assign it to `o`.

However, what if I want to assign the class itself into a variable and then instantiate it?

For example, suppose that I have two classes, such as `C1` and `C2`, and I want to do something like:

```
if (something):
   classToUse = C1
else:
   classToUse = C2

o = classToUse.instantiate()
```

What's the syntax for the actual `instantiate()`? Is a call to `__new__()` enough?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
o = C2()
```

This will accomplish what you want. Or, in case you meant to use classToUse, simply use:

```
o = classToUse()
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: So the semantics of adding () to a variable mean "treat as class and instantiate?"

Comment: () means "call this". Calling a class means instantiating it. Behind the scenes, calling something calls the __call__ metamethod, which you may use to make for example class *instances* callable as well.

Comment: In the previous comment call should probably be `__call__()`. (I hope formatting works this time.)

Comment: Aye, I got bitten by formatting again. Properly stated: Behind the scenes, calling something calls the `__call__()` metamethod. Thanks, Bastien Léonard.

Comment: Also note that `apply()` had to be used for this purpose before 2.3.

Answer (score 13):

You're almost there.  Instead of calling an instantiate() method, just call the variable directly.  It's assigned to the class, and classes are callable:

```
if (something):
    classToUse = C1
else:
    classToUse = C2

o = classToUse()
```

Answer (score 2):

It's simple, Python don't  recognize where a varible is a class or function. It's just call that value.

```
class A:
   pass
B=A
b=B()
```

Answer (score 0):

A class is an object just like anything else, like an instance, a function, a string... a class is an instance too. So you can store it in a variable (or anywhere else that you can store stuff), and call it with () no matter where it comes from.

```
def f(): print "foo"

class C: pass

x = f
x() # prints foo

x = C
instance = x() # instanciates C
```